# $L^2$ metric on $\textrm{Diff}(M)$ and geodesics

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, optimal-transportation

The paper [Geometry of diffeomorphism groups, complete integrability and optimal transport](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.0643.pdf) mentions the following:

> The group $\textrm{Diff}(M)$ carries a natural $L^2$-metric
>
> $\displaystyle \langle\langle u\circ\eta,
>  v\circ\eta\rangle\rangle_{L^2}=\int_{M}\langle u\circ \eta,v\circ
>  \eta\rangle d\mu=\int_{M}\langle u,v\rangle
>  \textrm{Jac}_{\mu}(\eta^{-1})d\mu \tag{2.10}$
> where $u,v\in T_{e}\textrm{Diff}(M)$ and $\eta\in \textrm{Diff}(M)$.

> ...Its significance comes from the fact that a curve $t \to η(t)$ in
> $\textrm{Diff}(M)$ is a geodesic if and only if $t \to η(t)(p)$ is a
> geodesic in $M$ for each $p \in M$.

I would like to know why the statement about geodesics holds. The paper does not give proof, so I tried to give proof myself, with no success.

It also feels too good to be true since I feel like the mapping $p\mapsto \eta(t)(p)$ has no guarantee that it is a diffeomorphism.

For what its worth, this statement is somehow removed in [the publication](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00039-013-0210-2.pdf?pdf=button).

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand your terminology, but I don't see how the function you've defined could be interpreted as a metric on $Diff(M)$.  Presumably you need a function of the form $Diff(M) \times Diff(M) \to \mathbb R$.  Aha, you are using "metric" in the sense of Riemann metric?

Comment: @RyanBudney Yes, it's about Riemannian metric. $M$ is Riemannian manifold too and $\langle\cdot,\cdot \rangle$ is Riemannian metric on $M$. I should have been clear about it.

Comment: What is the assumption going into your if and only if statement?  From the way you write it, I would assume the family $\eta(t)$ are always assumed to be diffeomorphisms.

Comment: @RyanBudney The paper isn't really clear about it, but it seems like $M$ is assumed to be compact or closed.  For me the case $M=\mathbb{R}^n$ is enough though.